# How can we split a string with out quotes using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string coming from database like Agree,don't,partially,completely. without quotes. I have taken this in to a variable and I have splitted.

```
    var x= Agree,Dont,Partially,completely;
    var split = x.split(',');
```

but the code is not working then i have inserted the quotes to the string like.

```
    var x = "\'" + answer coming from database + "\'";
    var split = x.split(',');
```

Then the code works out but i get the ans as

```
x[0] = "Agree,x[1]=Dont ... x[3] = Completely"
```

My question is how can i split the value without appending the quotes to the x.
Hope you understand my question

Reagrds,

Sri

Comment: Seems like you're missing some concepts there... A string is a string no matter where it comes from. The quotes are used in programming languages to _represent_ a string but a string itself does not have quotes around it. All you have to do is "import" that variable from the server into the client _as a string_.

Comment: Without quotes does not declare string in javascript variable.

Comment: How can we append quotes to grouped elements in c#

Comment: @naidu526: You're missing the point, you _don't_ need to append quotes to a string, quotes are needed to tell that the variable is of type string so the parser can interpret the code properly. Send your variable from c# _as a string_, possibly using JSON if that makes it easier...

Comment: @naidu526 , the other way is to get JSON string directly from db , if possible and use json parse function ( from a lib ) or other ways is to make a valid js array directly in query , eg. select '["apple","orange","pear"]' as js_array. I understand what you are talking , you might be replacing a js variable through template engine e.g var `js_array=<!--{JS_ARY}-->`. , in this case you need to place quotes around the variable e.g `js_array='<!--{JS_ARY}-->'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var x= "Agree,Dont,Partially,completely";
   var split = x.split(',');
   alert(split[0]+" "+split[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be:

```
var x = 'Agree,Dont,Partially,completely';
var split = x.split(',');
```

The quotation marks define the start and end of the string above.

Comment: From controller i am getting values like Agree,Dont,Partially,Completely then i appended like "\'" + answer coming from database + "\'"; when i split the code i am getting in array as 'Agree dont partially and completely'

Comment: Then, inspect that the generated JavaScript code looks like the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x= "Agree,Dont,Partially,completely";
var split = x.split(',');
```

This should give what you need